# C# Regex- find href with specific word in string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How can I find `href` attributes that include specific word?

I tried

```
"href=([?;.:=%-\/\\\'\"]+[a-zA-Z]*[blablabla][?;.:=%-\/\\\'\"]+[a-zA-Z]*$)"
```

However,  it doesn't match anything.

Comment: man.. just do it yourself.. https://regex101.com/

Comment: What have you tried? Please post. And as for *includes specific word inside the string*: what string you mean? "href" attribute value? And definitely it is a work for an HTML parser, not a regex.

Comment: somthing like this .var t = Regex.Match(input, @"href=yourword");have you googled it!!

Comment: I enter it "href=([?;.:=%-\/\\\'\"]+[a-zA-Z]*[blablabla][?;.:=%-\/\\\'\"]+[a-zA-Z]*$)", but it doesn't match anithing.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly advise against using regex in this case. I am sure using an HTML parser greatly facilitates the task.

Here is an example how it can be done with [**HtmlAgilityPack**](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). Install it via **Solution** > **Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...** and use

```
public List<string> HtmlAgilityPackGetHrefIfValueContains(string html, string href_text)
{
    var hrefs = new List<string>();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument hap;
    Uri uriResult;
    if (Uri.TryCreate(html, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult) && uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp)
    { // html is a URL 
        var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
        hap = doc.Load(uriResult.AbsoluteUri);
    }
    else
    { // html is a string
        hap = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        hap.LoadHtml(html);
    }
    var nodes = hap.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@href]");
    if (nodes != null)
    {
       foreach (var node in nodes)
       {
           foreach (var attribute in node.Attributes)
               if (attribute.Name == "href" && attribute.Value.Contains(href_text))
               {
                   hrefs.Add(attribute.Value);
               }
        }
    }
    return hrefs;
 }
```

Now, you can pass the `html` string or URL of the Web page, and  get all tags (if you plan to get `a` hrefs only, use `//a[@href]` xpath) that contain `href_text`.